# Theming Webform in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm trying to theme my webform but I can't seem to get the new webform_form_#.tpl.php to load properly. When I go to the node page I get a blank page on firefox with an empty body.

So in Template.php i've added the following line (my webform is on node 4)

```
function phptemplate_webform_form_4 ($form) {
  return _phptemplate_callback('webform_form_4', array('form' => $form));
}
```

I have a webform_form_4.tpl.php in my sites/all/theme/forest_floor/ directory which is a copy paste from the modules/webform/templates/webform-form.tpl.php

I've tried following the guide [here](http://drupal.org/node/79086), but I still get nothing when I visit the node page. Yes i've cleared the cache.

I've also tried removed everything in the webform_form_4.tpl.php and just added the 
`echo form_render($form);` like between `<?php ?>` and I still get nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A blank screen aka WSOD is properly due to a fatal PHP parse error. Try checking your apache error log.

Comment: The Drupal handbook has more information on how to troubleshoot [a white screen of death](http://drupal.org/node/158043).

Answer (score 0):

The link you are following on drupal node/79086 is for the older v4 of drupal Maybe this can help you http://drupal.org/node/335020

Answer (score 0):

Weird it won't let me login to reply (for some reason) it doesn't think i'm the one who wrote the question.

Checked the apache logs

PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function _phptemplate_callback() in template.php

Am I calling an old function?